# Get product quantity via ajax on product selected (Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 2 elements: a products list and a disabled quantity dropdown.

[image]

I want to get the quantity product to update the dropdown when the user select a product from the list.

My current code is the following:

**View**

```
        <%= f.label "Producto" %>
        <%= f.text_field :product_search, class: "form-control radius-top", value: '', placeholder: 'Buscar...', readonly: readonly  %>
        <%= select_tag "order_detail[product_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, "id", "name"), :include_blank => 'Seleccionar producto', :class => 'form-control radius-bottom' %>

        <%= f.label "Cantidad" %>
            <%= select_tag "order_detail[quantity]", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, "id", "name"), :include_blank => '0', :class => 'form-control radius-bottom', disabled: true %>
```

**Controller**

```
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @customers = Customer.all.order('name ASC')
    @products = Product.only_with_stock.order('name ASC')
    @product_details = ProductDetail.all
  end
```

**update_quantity.js.coffee**

```
$("#order_detail_quantity")
    .empty()
    .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @product_details)) %>")
```

The "#order_detail_quantity" is the quantity dropdown but I'm getting a Ajax error.

What could be bad?

I really need help :(

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**Product_details list partial**

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
  <h1 class="page-header">Inventario</h1>

    <%= link_to '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar</button>'.html_safe, new_product_product_detail_path(@product) %>

    <br><br>

    <% if !@product.product_details.empty? %>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Serial</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="text-center">Comentario</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  <% @product.product_details.each do |product_detail| %>
                    <tr>
                      <td><%= product_detail.id %></td>
                      <td><%= link_to product_detail.serial, edit_product_product_detail_path(@product, product_detail) %></td>
                      <td class="text-center"><span class="label label-<%= product_detail.product_status.available == true ? 'success' : 'danger' %>"><%= product_detail.product_status.name %></span></td>
                      <td class="text-center"><%= product_detail.comment.empty? ? '-' : product_detail.comment %></td>
                      <td class="text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-gear"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_product_product_detail_path(@product, product_detail) %><li>
                            <li><%= link_to 'Eliminar', [@product, product_detail], method: :delete, data: { confirm: '¿Seguro que deseas eliminar el articulo ' + product_detail.serial + '?' } %></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  <% end %>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    <% else %>

        <% if @product.published == true  %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger g-margin-b-0" role="alert">¡Este producto aun no tiene inventario y esta publicado!</div>
        <% else %>
            <div class="alert alert-warning g-margin-b-0" role="alert">Este producto aun no tiene inventario...</div>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: Just an ajax error, I think that It's returning the product_details, I don't know why

Comment: maybe `<%= render partial: "product", object: @product_details %>`

Comment: What do you have in that partial anyways?

Comment: I using your suggestion but I getting the same error :(

Comment: Don't put ERB into your CoffeeScript code. One advantage of CoffeeScript is the compilation and compression of Javascript code. Now if you bring dynamic Ruby code in, the CoffeeScript Compiler has to compile the code for every single request. I don't even know if this still works in the current Rails versions. Please take a look into your Chrome inspector if the Javascript code was compiled properly.

Comment: Do you want to see the view?

Comment: How can I call the partial without ERB into the coffeescript?

Comment: I already updated with my details partial

Comment: Take a look into the [Gon Gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon). It's pretty well described. Basically you set variables in your controller and they will be set as javascript variables in your view. In this way your javascript is always static and only the variables in your views are dynamically.

Comment: I think you have a fallacy here. I don't see any ajax request in your code. Technically you have to create an API. So a seperate action which delivers the content to the user for example in JSON or XML format. Take a look into [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Comment: If I'm not executing any Ajax, how I getting a ajax error?